# <h:selectBooleanCheckbox doesn't retrieve values on Server

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-webflow

I am using JSF along with RichFaces and Spring Webflow. I am trying to select rows from the data table using and perform some operation on the server side on the selected row. How ever I am facing problem retrieving the data from the checkbox.

```
<rich:column id="compCheckBox" styleClass="center-aligned-text">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="selectAll">
                                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                    <h:outputText value="Select"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectComponent" title="selectAll" value="#{workspace.selectedComponentIds[componentInfo.id]}">
                                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                            </rich:column>
```

And submitting the value using

However only the Ids are restored in the Map, and by default all the values of the ids in the map are shown as 'false'.

How do I get the selected checkboxes to get marked as true in the map.

I have referred [link text](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) for information.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks,
Abdul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the same datamodel is preserved in the subsequent request. The `value` attribtue of the datatable must return *exactly the same* datamodel during form submit as it was during display. If the datamodel is not present or different, then chances are that the map of selected items won't be filled as you'd expect.

---

**Update** as per the comment: you also need to ensure that the table and the submit button are inside the *same* `<h:form>`.

Comment: the map which i submit polulates the ids properly, the problem is only with the boolean value for the selected id.

Comment: To avoid the obvious: are the table and the submit button inside the same form?

Comment: Thanks soo much BalusC... You are a master stroke. It was just so silly of me to ignore the form.